# Angular ui-router with parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I try to use angular with ui-router. It works fine except in one case.
I've created a directive element which is the header of the page. This element has a menu with 4 links. These links depend on the id of the current user. This id is passed as an attribute when I call my directive.

**ui.js**

```
angular.module('app.ui', 
[

]).directive('userHeader', function()
{
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : '/scripts/directives/ui/userHeader.html',
        controller : function($scope)
        {

        },
        link : function(scope, element, attributes)
        {
            scope.uid = attributes.uid
        }
    };
});
```

**userHeader.html**

```
<md-list layout="row" class="md-whiteframe-z1 no-padding">
    <md-list-item class="has-link" layout-align="center center">
        <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="center center" ui-sref="userInformations({ id : '{{ uid }}' })">
            <div class="inset">
                <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">person</md-icon>
            </div>
            <md-tooltip hide-gt-sm>Informations</md-tooltip>
            <div class="inset" hide-sm>Informations</div>
        </md-item-content>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-list-item class="has-link" layout-align="center center">
        <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="center center" ui-sref="userEvents({ id : '{{ uid }}' })">
            <div class="inset">
                <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">event</md-icon>
            </div>
            <md-tooltip hide-gt-sm>Événements</md-tooltip>
            <div class="inset" hide-sm>Événements</div>
        </md-item-content>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-list-item class="has-link" layout-align="center center">
        <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="center center" ui-sref="userGalleries({ id : '{{ uid }}' })">
            <div class="inset">
                <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">photo</md-icon>
            </div>
            <md-tooltip hide-gt-sm>Galeries</md-tooltip>
            <div class="inset" hide-sm>Galeries</div>
        </md-item-content>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-list-item class="has-link" layout-align="center center">
        <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="center center" ui-sref="userFriends({ id : '{{ uid }}' })">
            <div class="inset">
                <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">group</md-icon>
            </div>
            <md-tooltip hide-gt-sm>Amis</md-tooltip>
            <div class="inset" hide-sm>Amis</div>
        </md-item-content>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

**user.html**

```
<user-header user-id="UserInformations.user.id"></user-header>
```

I don't know how to bind the user-id attribute to everu ui-sref attributes of my md-item-content so it can generate the correct link.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

If no data is passed into the directive is your problem

Change your code to this

```
<user-header user-id="{{UserInformations.user.id}}"></user-header>
```

---

```
link : function(scope, element, attributes)
{
    scope.uid = attributes.userId;

}
```

Also look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive on how to pass data to directive scope.

Comment: I've tried it before posting. It doesn't work. When I open chrome console I see that id is null

Comment: Even if id is not null, the generated href doesn't include it